# Error 122 from Storage Engine

Tags: mysql

Getting the following error message on the front end of the sites sub pages and not the home page of the site. I have fixed it before by optimising & repairing the database but it has come up again and would like to fix it permanently. EE 2.5.2

Error Number: 1030

Got error 122 from storage engine

SELECT c.cat_name, c.cat_url_title, c.cat_id, c.cat_image, c.cat_description, c.parent_id, p.cat_id, p.entry_id, c.group_id , cg.field_html_formatting, fd.* FROM (exp_categories AS c, exp_category_posts AS p) LEFT JOIN exp_category_field_data AS fd ON fd.cat_id = c.cat_id LEFT JOIN exp_category_groups AS cg ON cg.group_id = c.group_id WHERE  c.cat_id = p.cat_id AND  p.entry_id IN ('17') ORDER BY c.group_id, c.parent_id, c.cat_order

Filename: modules/channel/mod.channel.php

Line Number: 953

Answer (score 1):

OS error code 122: Disk quota exceeded

hence optimising and fixing before may have reduced and brought you back within limit... is this possible